# UI pattern for organizing/categorization where items can become a category?

Tags: drag-n-drop, categorization, organization

The picture below show pretty much where I am right now, category on the left & in my app I can drag items in categories & move it like that.

The issue I have right now is that an Item can be a category & I am unsure what would be the best way to handle this situation,

I'm thinking of having a settings button on hover & a way to create a category from an item.

Any other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to mix two interaction types: drag and drop and button. More consistent way is to support drag and drop operation for Category creation. See the picture.
[image]
Pay attention:

- `New category` label is a visible cue
- placing in on the top guarantees its visibility when there are many categories
- gray color doesn't distract and distinguish it from the existing categories

Comment: If you use any GTD ([Getting Things Done][1]) apps, you'll see this at work in

 [Omnifocus][2] desktop. These are essentially list containers, like many organization apps.

You can simply drag the task to the sidebar, and it becomes a project (similar to a category).

Alexey is spot on with the wireframe above.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done
  [2]: http://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus